# python UnboundLocalError referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I see that this seems to be a common error, but I'm not seeing the answer for my case.

> UnboundLocalError: local variable '`tfstate_dict`' referenced before  assignment

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json


def main():
    get_sfleet_id()

def get_sfleet_id():
    try:
        f=open("terraform_remote.tfstate", "r")
        contents =f.read()
        tfstate_dict = json.load(contents)

    except:
        print("error loading %s" % f)
    print(contents)
    print(tfstate_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: `tfstate_dict` only ever exists if your `try` code block succeeds.

Comment: doesn't my try code block succeed since it outputs 'print(contents)'?

Comment: No; your `print`s are _always_ executed since they are not _within_ the `try` branch.

Comment: I missed this error which is the culprit. error loading <_io.TextIOWrapper name='terraform_remote.tfstate' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'> How do I fix this?

Comment: The reason you missed the error is because you wrap everything in a bare `except` clause... Don't do that

Comment: You don't know what the error is, or which statement is came from.  All you are doing is printing a file object, not the error.  You should not use a bare `except`, and print the exception (`except as err` then print `err`)

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in my comment, `tfstate_dict` does not come in to existence until you exit your `try` block. But that's not to say that it applies to all the preceding code; it simply applies to `tfstate_dict` because it happens to be the very last line.

This is easily testable with the following:

```
try:
    a = int(2)
    b = int(3)
    c = int('hi')
except:
    print(locals())
    print()
    print(locals().get('a'))
```

You should see that `'a'` and `'b'` are both defined and can be accessed (depending on how you're running this code, there could a lot of stuff in `locals()` too). So, the existence of `'a'` and `'b'` gives you no assurance that `'c'` exists.

There's two issues with your current exception handling:

1. There's probably too much going on in your `try` block to be handled the way you currently do. This code will fail if the file cannot be located, but you wouldn't necessarily know that was happening. And if your code originally failed only on `tfstate_dict = json.load(contents)` you're now scratching your head why you're getting a `NameError` on `print(contents)` all of a sudden.
2. You don't want to be catching these issues with blanket `except`. At a minimum you'll want to use `except Exception as e:`, which allows you to print `e` too.

Here's a hypothetical situation where you handle the file not existing, and you also give a shot at parsing JSON.

```
import json
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

try:
    with open('something.json') as infile:
        try:
            #data = json.load(infile) # This is what you'd really use
            data = json.loads("{hi: 2}") # But let's make it fail
        except JSONDecodeError:
            print("Not valid JSON, try something else")
            data = infile.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Can't find file")
    data = ''
```

Comment: my json file is called 'terraform_remote.tfstate'  and when I use your example I get this:  <_io.TextIOWrapper name='terraform_remote.tfstate' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

Comment: @ikask without modifying my code printouts at all? What library are you using? Also note that this issue is separate to your actual question, which was how you could have an unnamed variable.